# obtain a full remote file size from a running remote process using command line tools

Tags: windows, batch-file, remote-access

I need to get the filesize of a remote executable file which its process is running on a remote xp machine.
it must be done from a Windows system using only a batch file and only from a command line.

sigcheck.exe cannot be used because it does not take control over remote files.

I can not even map the remote disk to do that.

Hope someone have a good solution.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that when you don't have enough permissions to map a drive or access it using an unc path you won't have permissions to list tasks. Before you spend time to create a batch for this check if your permissions are sufficient. You can use http://live.sysinternals.com/pslist.exe to list remote processes. I assume installing a software on the remote pc is not an option too ?

Comment: hi Marged, I have full admin permission on remote machine  but for other reasons dont want to map remote drive. Yes I can see all processes running on remote but what I need is to understand ( whitout a client installed on remote )  if runnuing remote executable  must be upgraded with a new version.  To understand that I have to check exe date  or exe version.

Comment: if you prefer to make your (work-)life complicated ;-) Why not simply do a quick `net use \\machine\ipc$ ...` and a short comparion of the remote file by using \\server\c$\some\path\your.exe ? After that you can do a quick `net use \\server\ipc$ /d` and you never had a drive letter mapped and the connection is gone afterwards.

Comment: is not a question to make my life complicate but I cannot map disk on remote workstation ( this is my big problem )  and this is why I ask  stackoverflow community for a "creative" solution respecting constraints that have rightly being indicated in my question.

Comment: is mapping the drive forbidden or is this an error ? If its an error you perhaps better ask how to solve the problem.

Comment: is forbidden. I appreciate your effort to find a solution.

Comment: I have no further ideas